# Questions about $\omega, f, \omega_{0}$ in harmonic oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, frequency

The motion equation for a mass-spring system is

$$x(t)=A\sin({\omega t+\phi})$$

where $A$ is amplitude and $\omega$ is vibration frequency. We have frequency value with $f$ and its inverse $T$. What is the difference between $\omega$ and $f$?

If there is an example for these terms, It would be nice.

Another questions is about the damped harmonic oscillator. In the damped harmonic oscillator, $\omega^2=\omega_0^2-\beta^2$. My teacher told that $\omega$ and $\beta$ are constant. I don't understand if $\omega$ is varying with time, how it can be constant?

Comment: *I don't understand if $\omega$ is varying with time, how it can be constant?* Why do you think that $\omega$ is varying with time? It’s not.

Comment: I'm not sure. But, for example consider that we have Mass-Spring system in a liquid. Then, if we release the mass from a distance ($\omega_0$), it will slow down and every time It's periot will increase (in my imagination). Isn't that correct? (I know i should not trust my senses everytime. Sorry for interpreting the system with my senses.)

Comment: Why did you say “distance ($\omega_0$)”? The frequency $\omega_0$ is not a distance.

Comment: *Isn't that correct?* No, not for what we call damped harmonic motion. The amplitude decreases but the period does not change. Either your senses are untrustworthy or you observed a system that is not accurately modeled by the equations for a damped harmonic oscillator.

Comment: In the future, please stick to asking one question per post. You shifted from talking about an undamped oscillator to a damped one, never defined what $\beta$ and $\omega_0$ are, never wrote the equations for damped motion, etc.

Comment: Are you using your *senses* or your *imagination*? These are very different things.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I confused $\omega_0$ with $x_0$. Actually the system was inside my brain, I filled a aquarium with honey then I started the horizontal mass-spring system (no gravity). However, if period doesn't change then frequency doesn't change too, right? So, there is no difference between non-damped harmonic oscillator and damped harmonic oscillator in context of frequency and period.

Comment: I'm sorry, I will do that next time. Thank you for your explanation. I think I got the thing that I misunderstand.

Comment: *there is no difference between non-damped harmonic oscillator and damped harmonic oscillator in context of frequency and period* No, there *is* a difference. When I said that the period does not change, I meant that it doesn’t change *with time* like you thought it did. But a damped oscillator *does* have a longer period / lower frequency than an undamped one. This is exactly what $\omega^2=\omega_0^2-\beta^2$ is saying. They are two different systems, with different periods and frequencies, but the period and frequency of each one is *constant*.

Comment: @G.Smith thank you. I really understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular frequency, $\omega$ is related to the time period $T$ via $\omega = 2\pi / T$. Evidently then we could also write $\omega = 2\pi f$.

To try and justify this, consider the trajectory for simple harmonic motion

$$x = A\sin{(\omega t + \phi)} \, .$$

If we increase $t$ by $2\pi / \omega$, then

$$x_2 = A\sin \left(\omega \left(t + \frac{2\pi}{\omega} \right) + \phi \right) = A\sin{(\omega t + \phi + 2\pi)}$$

Increasing $t$ by $2\pi / \omega$ has increase the phase by $2\pi$, so the object has returned to its previous position. This time increment is then interpreted as the time period of the oscillation.

As for your second question, to understand why the oscillator behaves the way it does under driving forces and/or damping, you really need to try and solve the differential equation for the motion. If you "underdamp" the oscillator, then you do indeed obtain the relationship $\omega^{2} = \omega_{0}^{2} - \beta^{2}$ where $\beta$ is the damping ratio.

Comment: We have solved the differential equation for the harmonic oscillator under a friction force that varies by the velocity. In the example the friction force was $F_{s}=-b\dot{x}$. So, $F_{\text{net}}=M\ddot{x}=-b\dot{x}-Cx \Rightarrow M\ddot{x}+b\dot{x}+Cx=0 \Rightarrow \ddot{x}+\frac{b}{M}\dot{x}+\frac{C}{M}x=0 \Rightarrow \ddot{x}+\frac{1}{\tau}\dot{x}+w_0^2 x=0$. We didn't solve this differential equation in a mathematician way, we solved it by solution proposal $x(t)=e^{-\beta t}x_{0}\sin(\omega t+\phi)$.

Comment: By doing this I have found the expression $\omega^2=\omega_0^2-\beta^2$. But sometimes I can't be able to understand the meaning of the equations. But, thanks for your help!

Comment: Physically, it just means that $\omega_{0}$ is the natural frequency of the oscillator in the absence of damping (using your notation, $\omega_{0} = \sqrt{\frac{C}{M}}$). Also, $\beta$ is proportional to the coefficient of velocity (in your example, $b$) and inversely proportional to the square roots of mass and the spring constant. Intuitively, the more damping in the system, the lower the natural frequency of your oscillator!

Answer (score 1):

For your first question already there is an answer on stack exchange

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/458311/252460

For your second question also , there is an answer to much deeper question, 
Although the question is not same ,but you will definitely get a great insight

[Is angular frequency dependent on time in damped harmonic motion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136535/252460)